# Why and when I would get -1 when i downvoted some questions or answers which is not appropriate?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

I tried to downvote an answer which i felt the reply was not an appropriate answer. But while doing so, I saw -1 reduced from my reputation score. But this was not the case with some other questions or answers. Why this is happening? On what condition or occasions does a -1 score gets deducted from our reputation score?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Help - What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation),

**You lose reputation when:**

- your question is voted down: −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer: −1
- you place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100

I've not seen a case where I've voted down a question without losing reputation. The help section goes on to say the following:

*All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not gain you any reputation. If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well. Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost or gained reputation.*

Perhaps you reversed your vote or voted down a question when you didn't have sufficient reputation for your reputation to drop? Its also possible the member left. In which case your downvote would have been restored. See [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed)

Comment: Also, you may not immediately lose the rep, so you won't necessarily notice it. It seems the loss comes after your vote is committed (5 minutes?), so it won't appear immediately, and if you don't pay attention, you'll never realize it was gone.

Comment: Also 2: when downvoted posts are deleted, you get your reputation back i believe

Comment: Have you ever seen a +1 in your feed upon receiving credit for a downvote that was cast on a question when it was taken from the hold queue and closed? I've never seen it happen here. The member who received the downvotes would seemingly also need to receive credit for the downvotes cast against their question for that to occur. I see no mention of that happening in the help sections and am skeptical that it occurs.